# How to compress or stretch a graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

I’m just wondering if you want to compress a graph in the horizontal direction, do you just place the number in front of the ‘x’? For example, if you have g(x) = 1/x, do you just place a 3 in front of the x (to become 1/3x) in order to compress it, and would you do the same for 0.3 (only it would stretch I believe)? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise you replace $x$ with $(kx)$ where $k$ is the amount of horizontal compression you wish to apply.  So, for instance, if you have $x^2$, you do $(kx)^2$; if you have $e^x$ you do $e^{(3x)}$.  This also applies to any other manipulations you wish to do that can be represented as $f(blah)$: you replace $x$ with $(blah)$.